# DJI Phantom 3 : Saving Live camera stream in android

Tags: java, android, dji-sdk

I followed the dji phantom 3 developer site and made the demo app myself. The Video is showing in my app. The drone already stores the video on a onboard memorycard. But I am looking for a way to save the live video stream in my android phone, so that its more convinient to process it in almost realtime.

```
// The callback for receiving the raw H264 video data for camera live view
mReceivedVideoDataCallBack = new DJICamera.CameraReceivedVideoDataCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onResult(byte[] videoBuffer, int size) {
        if(mCodecManager != null){
            // Send the raw H264 video data to codec manager for decoding
            mCodecManager.sendDataToDecoder(videoBuffer, size);
        }else {
            Log.e(TAG, "mCodecManager is null");
        }
```

Can anyone help to save the decoded video into a mp4 file? or Suggest me another way.

Comment: I am following this tutorial 

https://developer.dji.com/mobile-sdk/documentation/android-tutorials/FPVDemo.html

Comment: Try  this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33523053/decoding-video-stream-on-android-from-dji-drone